# Swift queue and delay process

Tags: node.js, swift, queue, delay

IN swift 3.0

I need to send a Dictionary on node server on click a  button, and a user can frequently Hit or click this button.

so I need to send this dictionary in the queue in one after one order with some delay. and in the same time user can HIT button multiple times, but the QUEUE will perform its work separately one by one, doesn’t dependent to button Click.
Here is my code

```
 func sendProductInCart(Product: NSString) {


        delayWithSeconds(5) {

            let msgToSend: String =  String.init(format: "__JSON__START__%@__JSON__END__", Product)

            print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
            print(msgToSend)

            let data: Data? = msgToSend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            _ = data?.withUnsafeBytes { self.outputStream.write($0, maxLength: (data?.count)!)
            }
        }
        }

func delayWithSeconds(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
            completion()
        }
    }
```

BUT this is not working . after 5 seconds all product send which comes in the range of this 5 sec. I need one at a time. 
Please share your valuable knowledge.

after 5 sec output is (I have click button on 10 times)

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"2","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:09","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"3","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:09","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"4","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:09","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"5","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:09","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"6","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:09","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"7","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:09","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"8","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:10","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"9","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:10","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"10","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:10","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
__JSON__START__{"type": "4","message": {"categoryid":"1","productId":"2","productprice":"10.00","productimage":"http:\/\/183.182.84.77:8082\/Content\/ProductImages\/chips2.JPG","productname":"B-Chips Premimum appetizer 40g -40","chanelname":"88719922048109810977","quantity":"11","producttype":"0","categoryName":"Alimentacion"}, "sender_id":"8109810977", "reciever_id": "8871992204", "time": "10-12-2017 05:16:10","connection_type":"cart"}__JSON__END__
```

Comment: So you need to wait for 5 seconds after order was sended, before allowing to make the next one, right? If yes then you can just add some kind of the lock screen and prevent any user interactions before the order will be sent. Or you need another behavior?

Comment: But I cant able to stop user interaction. It all think must be in the background .

Comment: It's not in the background because you are using the main queue to call the method for sending the dictionary. You should use the background queue for it. Why you can't stop user interactions? Is it a rule of the usability or what? Anyway, you can use background sync queue to send commands one by one. But you should return to the main queue after making any changes in the background, because all interface updates should be in the main queue